# Can you overlap a static-directory and a dynamic route in webapp2?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

For example if I have a physical directory with the name "files" and a static file called "file.html" but I also want to have a dynamic handler called "/files/hello_world".

How do you configure the app.yaml file to handle this case, so the static file loads and so does the handler?

Thanks!

Comment: If the physical directory is maped to a different url than 'files', yes.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what the app.yaml config would look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I handled it like this:

```
- url: /files/(.*\.(html|jsp|js|css|map|woff|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|tiff))$
  static_files: files/\1
  upload: files/(.*\.(html|jsp|js|css|map|woff|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|tiff))$

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

So now /files/index.html works and so does /files/do_something_dynamic

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

From App Engines [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles)

Just replace `some_uri` with your own and the `static_dir` stays the same as your directory is name `files`

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /some_uri
  static_dir: files
- url: /files/hello_world
  script: your_module.application
```

When the someone goes to `/some_uri/file.html` the forntend will look for a file called `file.html` in your `files` folder.